# How to send commands to a bot by name?

Tags: discord.py

Maybe need to specify the name as a prefix? How to implement this?
I've tried prefixing both @Name and @Name # 1111 and @ 54656466466 and just Name Name # 1111 34324324234234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mention string is not `@Name` or `@Id`, it's `<@Id>`. When using this for your prefix, there's a built-in function [`when_mentioned`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=when%20mentioned#discord.ext.commands.when_mentioned) that you can use.

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned, ...)
```

If you want to be able to use a (list of) prefix(es) AND mention it, use [`when_mentioned_or`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=when%20mentioned#discord.ext.commands.when_mentioned_or).

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('!'))
```

(where `'!'` is of course your prefix).

If you want to literally use his name without mentioning, just add it as a prefix. Keep in mind spaces in the name won't work, so either pick a name without spaces or write a custom prefix function that handles this.