# discord.py commands.when_mentioned not working with custom prefix

Tags: python, discord.py

**What I'm trying to do**: If someone doesn't know the prefix, they can mention the bot and use the mention instead. After some research, I had found [How to send commands to a bot by name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65379310/how-to-send-commands-to-a-bot-by-name) This made me want to try using the `commands.when_mentioned` or `commands.when_mentioned_or` functions alongside my custom prefix.

**My problem**: The bot either only responds to the mention (while throwing errors at me), or does not respond at all.

Here is the custom prefix code I am using: [How to get a customizable prefix discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64513680/how-to-get-a-customizable-prefix-discord-py/64513681#64513681)

Here is the client definition with the `command_prefix`:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix= (get_prefix),
    description='A bot who wants your toes',
    owner_id=(394506589350002688),
    case_insensitive=True,
    intents=intents
    )
```

**Below I have listed what I have tried. I am not sure what to try next, so I will be grateful for any help provided.**

Trial 1:

```py
command_prefix= commands.when_mentioned_or((get_prefix))
```

Result:

```
TypeError: Iterable command_prefix or list returned from get_prefix must contain only strings, not function
```

Trial 2:

```py
command_prefix= commands.when_mentioned or (get_prefix)
```

Result: No error, but bot no longer responds to custom prefix as seen below.

[image: Bot does not respond to bl!]

Trial 3:

```py
command_prefix= commands.when_mentioned and (get_prefix)
```

Result: No error, but bot no longer responds to mention as seen below.

[image: Bot no longer responds to mention]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`when_mentioned_or` is supposed to be passed a list of prefixes, not a function for getting that list.  It's easy enough to modify though:

```
def when_mentioned_or_function(func):
    def inner(bot, message):
        r = func(bot, message)
        r = commands.when_mentioned(bot, msg) + r
        return r
    return inner
```

Comment: so command_prefix=when_mentioned_or_function(get_prefix)? or when_mentioned_or_function(commands.when_mentioned_or(get_prefix))

Comment: @StatTrakDiamondSword the first one

Comment: I checked the example on readthedocs and it is actually really simple. In the get_prefix function, you return `commands.when_mentioned_or(prefix)(bot, message)`